# Does the Content Security Policy Standard support wildcard paths? If not, why doesn't it?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, cdn, content-security-policy

From reading the [CSP Standard specification and examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) it seems that it does not support wildcards in the path portion of a given URL.  This seems like an oversight, as many CDNs and static file hosting providers share the root domain names between their users and only differentiate access on URL paths rather than the entire domain.

For example, when using S3 or Google Cloud Storage as a CDN, you might want a CSP to allow scripts/assets to be loaded from just your bucket with a wildcard URL like "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-apps-bucket/*" but disallow them for the rest of https://storage.googleapis.com, as it would be rather trivial for a malicious actor to create their own account and serve content from that root domain.

This seems like a pretty common use case, am I misunderstanding the spec?  If not, what is the syntax to use wildcard paths, as utilizing a header like `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://example.com/*` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The "matching source expressions" part of the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#match-source-expression) describes the URL matching algorithm in detail.  It does support what you're asking for, but you don't use the wildcard character.

The spec discusses the optional "path-part" of the allowed sources, and says if the allowed URL ends in a slash "/", it is a prefix match rather than an exact match.

So, in your example, if you allow

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-apps-bucket/
```

with a slash but without the asterisk on the end, it will match files below that URL, for example

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my-apps-bucket/file1.js
```

Comment: This is now at [URL Matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#matching-urls) and in particular [part-path matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#match-paths) in the working draft.

Comment: Will `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-apps-bucket/` also match `https://storage.googleapis.com/my-apps-bucket` ?

Comment: I'm trying to write a CSP for htaccess mod_headers. /about/index.html
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';object-src 'none';script-src 'self' 'sha256-Ky9qZOPnMhQV/s7Fdb9TYAOfU4KtWNqCZaFK8tSzXa0=';style-src 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' data: ????